# vba: log cleaning macro: how to optimize for faster execution?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I'm running a macro that I made to delete the log contents and reformat the table in case that any format changes occurred while using it, the macro does what I intended but it takes about 30 minutes to finish running, all the while excel is completely frozen and unusable. Upon checking task manager on the process usage column, it seems excel is only using about 12.5% of my processing capacity, is there any way that I can make this multithread or that I can optimize the code to not take forever?

P.S. I decided to apply the merging of cells in batches as I figured doing it for all cells at once might have been what was making the code run much slower but I didn't notice any real difference in execution time.

Code below:

```
Sub ClearAndFormatLogTable()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Easy Mode") ' Replace with your sheet name
    
    ' Turn off ScreenUpdating and Events to improve performance
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    ' Clear values and formats from range A7 to J50000
    ws.Range("A7:J50000").ClearContents
    ws.Range("A7:J50000").ClearFormats
    
    ' Merge cells in the first row (row 7)
    ws.Range("C7:J7").Merge
    ws.Range("C7").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
    
    ' Copy format from the merged cell
    ws.Range("C7").Copy
    
    ' Apply the format in batches
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 8 To 50000 Step 1000
        ws.Range("C" & i & ":J" & Application.Min(i + 999, 50000)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Next i
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False ' Clear the copy mode
    
    ' Apply thick borders and dotted inner vertical divisions
    With ws.Range("B7:J50000")
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThick
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThick
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThick
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlDot
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlDot
    End With
    
    ' Turn ScreenUpdating and Events back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can't really speed this up then maybe consider having a pre-formatted range on a hidden sheet which you can copy-paste in one operation over to "easy Mode"   Or replace the whole sheet with a copy of a hidden template sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub ClearAndFormatLogTable()
'Counter=0  Turn off the Counter
Counter = 1: stTime = Timer
'....................................................................................................
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Easy Mode") ' Replace with your sheet name
    
    ' Turn off ScreenUpdating and Events to improve performance
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    ' Clear values and formats from range A7 to J50000
    ws.Range("A7:J50000").ClearContents
    ws.Range("A7:J50000").ClearFormats
    
    ' Merge cells in the first row (row 7)
    ws.Range("C7:J7").Merge
    ws.Range("C7").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection

    'By using fill down instead of copy paste, results are obtained in 20-30 seconds.
    With ws.Range("C7:J50000")
        .FillDown
    End With
    
    ' Apply thick borders and dotted inner vertical divisions
    With ws.Range("B7:J50000")
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThick
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThick
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThick
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlDot
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlDot
    End With
    
    ' Turn ScreenUpdating and Events back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
'....................................................................................................
    If Counter = 1 Then MsgBox _
    Round(Timer - stTime, 2) & " second", vbInformation, "Macro Time"
End Sub
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could elaborate what's the diffence between your solution and the one of OP and why you think yours is faster.

Comment: By using fill down instead of copy paste, results are obtained in 20-30 seconds.

Comment: Although this is a nice approach (and personally I think there's no better one to the problem statement), I'd strongly suggest whenever faced with the scenario to basically clean and recreate a sheet follow TimWilliams comment: keeping a sheet format that you basically duplicate each run makes a lot make easier if there are changes later on.

Comment: @Sgdva Thanks for the suggestion, I will check that out, I didn't think of that solution as one would normally try to keep the workbook as clean and minimal as possible while the macro does all the work but it does make sense to do it how you suggest for super fast execution, perhaps I can just hide the template!

Comment: @cranky How am I supposed to declare this counter? as an Integer, single?

Comment: @RicardoBarreraVillarreal Integer

Comment: Thank you @cranky, this solution really helped my case, I can now run the macro in under one minute!

Comment: @RicardoBarreraVillarreal if this helped you and solved the problem, please check the answer with the green arrow :)

Comment: @Sgdva thanks for pointing it out, just checked the green checkmark!

Comment: @RicardoBarreraVillarreal @cranky : Always use `Long`, not `Integer` to prevent overflow errors. `Integer` used only 2 bytes in the old days, but since 32bit OS, it's occupying 4 bytes anyhow, and the VBA runtime artificially limit it to use only 2 bytes for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter version of setting borders:

```
Sub AddBorders()
    Dim tm As Double, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    tm = Timer
    ' Apply thick borders and dotted inner vertical divisions
    With ws.Range("B7:J50000")
        .Clear
        .BorderAround xlContinuous, xlThick
        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlDot
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlDot
    End With
    MsgBox "Czas = " & Timer - tm    ' 0.95 s Borders
                                     ' 0.6 s BorderAround
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help MGonet, hadn't realized I had this option!